# How to know which line in a python library raised an exception?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-asyncio, uvicorn

I have a program which runs fine but when I use uvicorn, my program raises an `asyncio.exceptions.CancelledError` when I call `asyncio.gather(*tasks)`. The problem is I don't know which line in the library (uvicorn or some other library) is rasing that exception.

How can I know which line in which library is rasing the exception?

Comment: What is your code, full error message?

Comment: Usually, the line will be written somewhere in the error message. Please add the code and the full error message for further inspection.